# How can I have common tooltip for a grid in Apache echart?

Tags: javascript, echarts, apache-echarts

I have two line charts in a grid so that I can have common zooming. Now, I want to have tooltip such that when I hover on one chart, tooltip popups in other as well. So, I can see, how the values are in both charts at the specific x-axis value.

Below is my code,

```
let base = +new Date(1968, 9, 3);
let oneDay = 24 * 3600 * 1000;
let date = [];
let values1 = [Math.random() * 300];
let values2 = [Math.random() * 300];
for (let i = 1; i < 20000; i++) {
  var now = new Date((base += oneDay));
  date.push(i)
  // date.push([now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 1, now.getDate()].join('/'));
  values1.push(Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20 + values1[i - 1]));
  values2.push(Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20 + values2[i - 1]));
}

option = {
  // tooltip: {
  //   trigger: 'none',
  //   // position: function (pt) {
  //   //   return [pt[0], '10%'];
  //   // }
  // },
  toolbox: {
    feature: {
      dataZoom: {
        yAxisIndex: 'none'
      },
      restore: {},
      saveAsImage: {}
    }
  },
  grid: [
    {
      // left: '3%',
      // right: '4%',
      top: '50%',
      containLabel: true,
      // show: true
    },
    {
      // left: '3%',
      // right: '4%',
      bottom: '50%',
      containLabel: true,
      // show: true
    },
  ],
  xAxis: [
    {
      type: 'category',
      boundaryGap: false,
      data: date,
      gridIndex: 0,
    },
    {
      type: 'category',
      boundaryGap: false,
      data: date,
      gridIndex: 1,
    },
  ],
  yAxis: [
    {
      type: 'value',
      boundaryGap: [0, '100%'],
      gridIndex: 0,
    },
    {
      type: 'value',
      boundaryGap: [0, '100%'],
      gridIndex: 1,
    },
  ],
  dataZoom: [
    {
      type: 'inside',
      // start: 0,
      // end: 10
      xAxisIndex: [0, 1],
    },
    // {
    //   // start: 0,
    //   // end: 10
    //   xAxisIndex: [0, 1],
    // }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Fake Data',
      type: 'line',
      symbol: 'none',
      sampling: 'lttb',
      itemStyle: {
        color: 'rgb(255, 70, 131)'
      },
      areaStyle: {
        color: new echarts.graphic.LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1, [
          {
            offset: 0,
            color: 'rgb(255, 158, 68)'
          },
          {
            offset: 1,
            color: 'rgb(255, 70, 131)'
          }
        ])
      },
      data: values1,
      gridIndex: 0,
      xAxisIndex: 0,
      yAxisIndex: 0,
    },
    {
      name: 'Faker Data',
      type: 'line',
      symbol: 'none',
      sampling: 'lttb',
      itemStyle: {
        color: 'rgb(255, 70, 131)'
      },
      areaStyle: {
        color: new echarts.graphic.LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1, [
          {
            offset: 0,
            color: 'rgb(255, 158, 68)'
          },
          {
            offset: 1,
            color: 'rgb(255, 70, 131)'
          }
        ])
      },
      data: values2,
      gridIndex: 1,
      xAxisIndex: 1,
      yAxisIndex: 1,
    }
  ]
};
```

The above code will render 2 charts with common zooming. I tried tooltip with item, axes and none but they didnt work.

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution 1

First, when using this kind of chart (with xAxis), it's recommanded to use `trigger: "axis"`.

Then to connect the tooltip, what you actually want to do is to connect the axisPointer :

```js
// add this to your chart option
axisPointer: {
  link: [
    {
      xAxisIndex: 'all'
    }
  ]
},
```

This being done, your 2 tooltips will be connected. But echart seems to struggle to display the tooltip on large dataset using `xAxis.type = 'category'` (20K points in your example). If you want to use big dataset with 'date' format on x, I recommand this :

- Format you series like a list of [date, value]
- Use `xAxis.type = 'time'`
- Remove `xAxis.data`

[Here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=area-basic&code=DYUwLgBARghgziCBeCBqAdiA7hAIjMEACgEYBOANgA4AaCMugZgEoBuAWAChRIB7TfAE9kEAEwAWCACoIjCgAZ50iCUXyO3cBAAmBRCgDaAXQ08IANxjAAriDgkRBg7AR0AsgQAWAOgBOMdG1eAFsiZmVGRSMTLjNLGztRR2d4EHcvPwCg0PCZSPlojQAzXl8IIjMASxESVghqgB4xNXV61FRwgG8uCAsYMvReHBRMHHxCIiIXRFQUfhAhZjYeiAB6Vd1CbwAHazhPIgNBrG8Ac3AAMWtgYABNEH6wumOz8Dd-MAPw1BVnodewONiMwjN4AFa8SroIgAclWMKWK3itnsOz2ByOQ3Snz8vGsgUmHhx_kCITCEAAtBB5N4AKy5ZrfPoJewGapUkhGAycozLTi9ZGJNH7Q7HbE-Xx4glEIkSrJk8JUmn05SieRMwVwURsykqLk8vkAXy4XF42zAlX4Im6_IgYF4vGAFu2AC4IDber0wL5Kqdzr43TCYAAPSpwGE0FaGyOcENhgAKkPQhAD7pWwChAGs3QYVr0PZ7esGAIKhuAASUCIGDgaswBheYgxttRi40ZW9sdUF4NbTtt6RQeYGsvhAboLhc2MAAWg7guPG4XBKWw5XtNXA4NMA3-5727veqO4PbR-P94XenAYOYQMWK8EYOcz43m71zxBTj7tDnGxPPesIFAIowEDRgAFII0XNZVggH1Tk8ECIBhcQIJjC87TNQNaXkVCoIAYw-GAoQAGRgKAQGAN1vVsNCLwA_Yhio3xbBfWj8yggCgMQmFwMgg9oNg30EMDFC-PQ7swHteckOw3D-II5MiPQUjyMou1mLSDiYIYrAmJY3d3yMWiSzLH9dz_L1BG2MckItYIQDEi9u3xXRfEEABxGBXQgIorFcKDP0qbQ1w3ak2KbcKLLtKybJhOyHPC3pnMCfoPK8t1fOAfz-MC4Kq17EhwsM2jl1MiBc3MqCwBiwNBUcwtktctLvIMeQ6BhVQcJhIyAq_ELeza1jfyqmqkLqxLoClJrPJatqkM6iCepyvr8rdQqhpbWip1nEIzMLKLquswMoTgIKEq0iBj36RDBv4gCQECNb5CgkzV1W8q5s5IrwoAv8AN6eiwGut1bsLf6BIe78VGe3dwdeit3taugvsbADXwgJbLxAH07D2z0ovQGB7MDC4YEzRBxhgerPUO2KM23Ca4EEYJuzUmEt3O_ir2CbZ6dOQMnTAKBqd6SpCGCABlarQAXfjegI4BSkDXxTigIhRFpWk6AAdk-xgSGYHd0PfQt-geKXBBlvt0Plx0lYgUYIBAPDPGuuAzn8bZPEqPDvGIqEHl8dz_G0SoHrAIg5qj5G6Aqm38ag9DeCKIoEBuib0IV-2YRVtWNa1lRaVoCBqENxO9wzhO5YvZPU_ANbK8LLPUxz1X1c1nW9YNo346bcveSgk3PSnN1NXW5agv6kGJvhqewqg0q3vXAbvuG_jCeJpDSfJspKZF6KjqQ-nOfQpmWcdTd5n37neahfmj8k4WJrFkBJelmyottxWW9z9uC915G-sy78SHr0M2MALZW0_hAZubpHbO1dr4MA7tPxeW9r7f2mB-jBxgKHcOkc6DR1-OVcu7Fq6FlrmnaepDPSwKQr_fOyMi50FLj3eOoCLzQIoSnKhvwaFf2zgwjuEAAEqCAWwm26N0IDxARNEezIUSiAmrlOe490Kz3emoi8i8EbLwbi-FYrZOCGlYEAA) is the full working code of your example.

---

### Solution 2

Another solution would be to create 2 separate charts and to connect them (zoom, tooltip ...) using

```js
echarts.connect([chart1, chart2]);
```

Here is what the code would look like with this method :

```js
var myChart1 = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main1'));
var myChart2 = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main2'));

let base = +new Date(1968, 9, 3);
let oneDay = 24 * 3600 * 1000;
let date = [];
let values1 = [Math.random() * 300];
let values2 = [Math.random() * 300];
for (let i = 1; i < 200; i++) {
  var now = new Date((base += oneDay));
  date.push(i)
  // date.push([now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 1, now.getDate()].join('/'));
  values1.push(Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20 + values1[i - 1]));
  values2.push(Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20 + values2[i - 1]));
}

var option1 = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
  },
  xAxis: [
    {
      type: 'category',
      boundaryGap: false,
      data: date
    }
  ],
  yAxis: [
    {
      type: 'value',
      boundaryGap: [0, '100%'],
    },
  ],
  dataZoom: [
    {
      type: 'inside',
    },
  ],
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Fake Data',
      type: 'line',
      symbol: 'none',
      sampling: 'lttb',
      itemStyle: {
        color: 'rgb(255, 70, 131)'
      },
      areaStyle: {
        color: new echarts.graphic.LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1, [
          {
            offset: 0,
            color: 'rgb(255, 158, 68)'
          },
          {
            offset: 1,
            color: 'rgb(255, 70, 131)'
          }
        ])
      },
      data: values1,
    },
  ]
};

var option2 = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
  },
  xAxis: [
    {
      type: 'category',
      boundaryGap: false,
      data: date
    }
  ],
  yAxis: [
    {
      type: 'value',
      boundaryGap: [0, '100%'],
    },
  ],
  dataZoom: [
    {
      type: 'inside',
    },
  ],
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Faker Data',
      type: 'line',
      symbol: 'none',
      sampling: 'lttb',
      itemStyle: {
        color: 'rgb(255, 70, 131)'
      },
      areaStyle: {
        color: new echarts.graphic.LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1, [
          {
            offset: 0,
            color: 'rgb(255, 158, 68)'
          },
          {
            offset: 1,
            color: 'rgb(255, 70, 131)'
          }
        ])
      },
      data: values2,
    },
  ]
};

myChart1.setOption(option1)
myChart2.setOption(option2)

echarts.connect([myChart1, myChart2]);
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.3.2/echarts.min.js"></script>
    <div id="main1" style="width: 600px; height:200px;"></div>
    <div id="main2" style="width: 600px; height:200px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wonder how to have the same effect as in solution 2 (separate tooltips) using the solution 1 - but as you move your mouse left and right.